# How can I write -5 +3 time deviation or -5, +3 time deviation?

Tags: punctuation, mathematics, numbers

Can I write "based on the arrival time deviation  of -5, +3 minutes" with comma or "-5 and +3 minutes" or "-5+3 minutes"?

> From 17 tours, the route was detected 13 times since the detection is accomplished based on the arrival time deviation of -5, +3 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it this way:

> From 17 tours, the route was detected 13 times, since the detection is accomplished based on *an* arrival time deviation of **-5/+3 minutes**.

Since there was more than one "arrival time", I would use *an*, not *the*.